# Excel to CSV Plugin for Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to develop a reusable component in Pentaho which will take an Excel file and convert it to a CSV with an encoding option.

In short, I need to develop a transformation that has an Excel input and a CSV output.
I don't know the columns in advance. The columns have to be dynamically injected to the excel input.

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfect candidate for [Pentaho Metadata Injection](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/ETL_Metadata_Injection). 
You should have a template transformation wich contains the basic workflow (read from the excel, write to the text file), but without specifiying the input and/or output formats. Then, you should store your metadata (the list of columns and their properties) somewhere. In Pentaho example an excel spreadsheet is used, but you're not limited to that. I've used a couple of database tables to store the metadata for example, one for the input format and another one for the output format.

Also, you need to have a transformation that has the Metadata Injection step to "inject" the metadata into the template transformation. What it basically does, is to create a new transformation at runtime, by using the template and the fields you set to be populated, and then it runs it.

Pentaho's example is pretty clear if you follow it step by step, and from that you can then create a more elaborated solution.

Comment: Is there a way to make it dynamic like excel in any format(number, text) create the corresponding  text file

Comment: @UmeshKumar could you please elaborate more? I don’t really understand what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: I have an excel file and i need to convert it to a csv file. I am trying to develop a reusable transformation which can take any excel and convert it to a csv  file. It should be a generic one,

Comment: I can't think of a way to achieve that. Pentaho needs to know beforehand what's the content of the file it has to read. In my case, I've used MySQL tables to store the metadata information of the input and output files. There, I store the columns and atributes of the excel file and that way PDI knows how to read the excel file and how to write the output file. That's a soluction based on the Metadata Injection example, which I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least two steps in a transformation:

Input step: Microsoft Excel input

Output step:  Text file output

[image]

Comment: Hi can you let me know how we can make the column in the excel input as dynamic columns?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, explain it in more detail? Please add the information to your initial question by editing that.

Answer (score 0):

So, Here is the solution. In your Excel Input Component, in Fields Section, mention maximum number of fields which will come in any excel. Then Route the Input excel to text field based on the Number of fields which are actually present. You need to play switch/case component here.[image: ETL-CODE]